# WS2812 LEDs with ESP32-schemantic

Tags: led, resistors, schematics, esp32, ws2812b

I have a [WS2812 LED module](https://botland.store/led-strings-chains-matrices/6255-led-strip-rgb-ws2812-5050-x-8-leds-53mm-5903351249157.html) I want to interface with an ESP32. I want to use a button and a sensor to control the LEDs.

I am not sure if the schematic is OK. Do I need a resistor for the LEDs, and if so, what value should the resistor be?

I tried to search on Google but I have seen many versions and don't know which is the good one.

[image]

Comment: Have you seaeched this site? Similar questions get asked occasionally. One thing is that the MCU data output pin is 3.3V and the LED data input needs 5V signal level. The PIR sensor output may be 5V, but MCU cannot handle 5V and may get damaged. Some level shifting between 5V and 3.3V may be required on that too.

Comment: You should also link the datasheet for your PIR sensor too, I googled but can't find anything with that part number.  I would leave pads for a resistor on the data line driving the LEDs, but you probably can put in zero ohm resistors unless you have long cables.  This will be more important if you pick a faster level translator IC.